# How do I get the auto-incrementing value of the last inserted record in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Using sqlite3, I inserted a new row into table Foo.

INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (colX=?, colY=? colZ=?)

Then I bind and execute the query. This table contains an auto-incrementing column as the primary key. How do I get at this ID after a new row was added without doing a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sqlite3_last_insert_rowid:

```
sqlite3_int64 sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(sqlite3*);
```

This gets the last inserted id, just like you asked.

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html

Comment: You might want to include some relevant info along with the link. At some point the URL may not work.