# Retrieve primary key from sqlite entry

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro

how do I retrieve the primary key of SQLite entries that populate a listview? I want to retrieve the primary key for the highlighted listview item. `entryList`
is my listview.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "data.db");
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
    {
        db.CreateTable<Person>();

        db.RunInTransaction(() =>
        {
            db.Insert(new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
        });
        entryList.ItemsSource = db.Table<Person>();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    [AutoIncrement,PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", LastName, FirstName, ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5938713

Comment: @RobertHarvey How can this be a duplicate? I don't want the last row inserted. I want the pk of an entry I might have done weeks ago.

Comment: Include the PK in your ListView, and hide the column that contains it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That is the idea I had, hoever, I am not entirely clear how to separate the pk from the rest of the entry into a separate column.

Comment: Hm? It's just a field, like any other. Bind it to its own column in the ListView.  Set the column's width to zero (or whatever you do to hide a column in a Metro ListView).

Comment: my listview itemssource is set to a table in my database. I am not clear on how to separate specific columns of my database to specific columns of my listview

Comment: Well, that's beyond my pay grade, but here's where I'd start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx